# Is there any way to control the stereo balance of the audio playback

Tags: media-player, audio

I cant find any controls/settings that allow this...not all of us have perfectly balanced ears

Answer (score 3):

Apparently there is such an app that can do this (see [this XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8254560&postcount=12)).

However, it's my understanding that to do this would require at minimum a rooted phone, and probably a custom kernel as well.  I don't know of any custom kernels that have this functionality, however.  You could also buy headphones with separate L/R volume controls.

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure I want to mess around, with mods, just to do this...